# javascript color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I take this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeBmt

```
function updateColor(hexValue) {
    $('a').css({"color" : "#" + hexValue});
}

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var hexValue = $(this).attr('data-color');
    updateColor(hexValue); 
});
```

and make it only change the color if the hex value of `a` is `#dddddd`
?

Comment: Just to clarify, only change the color if the _current_ color of `a` is `#dddddd`?

Comment: Looking at the code you linked to it's hard to tell what you want it to do.  You are referring to the 'color' as a CSS property that you want to change, but the elements all have a 'background' rule assigned to them.  There is a 'data-color' attribute applied to them but this isn't CSS.

Comment: Also calling `.css("color")` returns the rgb value (even if you use hex notation to define it)

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('a').css('color') == '#dddddd') {
    $('a').css({"color" : "#" + hexValue});
}
```

Put this in the function.

**EDIT**

```
function updateColor(obj, hexValue) {
    obj.css("color",hexValue);
}
$('a').click(function() {
    if($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(221, 221, 221)'){
        var hexValue = $(this).data('color');
        updateColor($(this), hexValue);
    }     
});
```

This works. My mistake about the rgb thing. Have a fiddle too. http://jsfiddle.net/SYBez/1/

But like @JasonSperske said, once the color changes, your code loses it's ability to function as the color has changed. I have no idea of the purpose of what you are trying to do, but I would go about this using, data, classes, or something else as relying on a color as a selector seems strange to me.

Comment: Or you can add a call to jQuery's .filter() function like this: `$('a').filter(function() {return $(this).css('color') == '#dddddd';})`

Comment: You mean like this:

function updateColor(hexValue) {
    if($('a').css('color') == '#dddddd') {
    $('a').css({"color" : "#" + hexValue});
}
});

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var hexValue = $(this).attr('data-color');
    updateColor(hexValue);
});

? It doesn't work!

Comment: `$('a').css('color') == '#dddddd'` will never be true (see my answer)

Comment: So couldn't he just change `#dddddd` to the rgb equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this may not be the answer you were looking for, but this code will do (I think) what you are asking ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYBez/)).  First off you need to made some changes to your markup (I've tried to show various permutations of those changes and how each will work)

Lets start with the HTML. Here I added a CSS rule (called `Change`) with the color `#ddddd`, and an inline style with the short version of the same color (`#ddd`)

```
<ul>
  <li data-color="f00">Red</li>
  <li data-color="0f0">Green</li>
  <li data-color="00f">Blue</li>
  <li data-color="ff0">Yellow</li>
  <li data-color="f0f">Purple</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class='Change'>Look at my color</a>
<a href="#">Look at my color</a>
<a href="#" class='Change'>Look at my color</a>
<a href="#">Look at my color</a>
<a href="#" style='color: #ddd;'>Look at my color</a>
```

Then the CSS (your CSS has a lot of rulees to colro each box, I just added this one:

```
a.Change {
  color: #dddddd;
}
```

Finally the script:

```
function updateColor(hexValue) {
  $('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(221, 221, 221)';
  }).css({
    "color": "#" + hexValue
  });
}

$('body').on('click', 'li', function () {
  var hexValue = $(this).attr('data-color');
  updateColor(hexValue);
});
```

If you click on one of the blocks then only the links who have a color of `#dddddd` (`rgb(221, 221, 221)`) will be updated.  However once you update them they will no longer have your original color so clicking on it a second time won't work (which is why I wonder if this answer is actually helpful to what you are trying to do))